# Very poor performance by Nhibernate & Unitwork pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have one complex object like this

```
 A
|
|
|                 |->C(As child)---->it has 4 hastomany properties(each B has 10000 C child)
B(has many child)->
                  |->D(As child)---->it has 4 hastomany properties(each B has 1o000 D child)
                  |->B Has many prop also
|
|
|A has many prop also
```

I, m suffering with performance. All together while retrieving this record i can expect Nh to fire 1000-2000 queries. But Worst performance by NH 10-20K queries it is firing.

Here i m doing reading and writing on entity A only. I'm not individually inserting any of A's child nor retrival. I'm firign Get command on entity A and writing back Entity A only.

Cascading is taking care of insertion of A's child->its child too.

here im suffering with Performace very badly, i dont know what to do here.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your mappings are eagerly fetching all of those children which I would not do.  It's hard to say without looking at your mappings but if you see something like this in your mappings this is your problem:

```
HasMany(x => x.OrderLines)
            .FetchType.Select();
```

or

```
HasMany(x => x.OrderLines)
            .FetchType.Join();
```

This means when you load the parent object all of these collections will also be loaded which can lead to the infamous "select n+1" problem.

Below is from the nhibernate documentation:

> (3)    fetch (optional, defaults to join): enables outer-join or
>   sequential select fetching for this association. This is a special
>   case; for full eager fetching (in a single SELECT) of an entity and
>   its many-to-many relationships to other entities, you would enable
>   join fetching not only of the collection itself, but also with this
>   attribute on the  nested element.

If you are unable to change your mappings I would recommend creating queries up front to get all the child collections.  This way you are only doing 1 query per entity rather than the 1000's nhibernate is doing currently via lazy loading.